# Why I don't have ADO.NET when I click "add item" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I don't have ADO.NET when I click add item in Visual Studio. I have several versions installed in my computer. In some of them, I have ADO.NET so how to download ADO.NET separately?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is located in "Data" on left side of your window.

Comment: It is not available in all sections. I typed "ADO.NET" in the search bar but no result.

Answer (score 1):

You should select the Web option then you select ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

[image]

Comment: I did and I checked all sections but still I don't see it. I have Visual Studio 2013 and I see it but in both 2017 and 2019, I don't. By the way, I downloaded Visual Studio with all web workloads. I don't know if ADO.NET comes in another packages or what?